# Invalid Placement Combinations during Campaign creation Instagram

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-api

During a campaign creation in Instagram throw Facebook API I got this error:

```
 400 - "{\"error\":{\"message\":\"Invalid parameter\",\"type\":\"OAuthException\",\"code\":100,\"error_subcode\":1815336,\"is_transient\":false,\"error_user_title\":\"Invalid Placement Combinations\",\"error_user_msg\":\"The placement combination selected is not supported by the set up of the campaign.\",\"fbtrace_id\":\"XXXXXXX\"}}
```

Someone of you know the reason? Facebook's documentation doesn't says nothing about, the error sub code is not been mapped in the docs.
It looks like there is something wrong in the target combination like combo of language-locations-ages but I don't understand the rules

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the target devices, Instagram Campaign cannot have target devices only Desktop. They MUST include Mobile devices.
I hope this will be useful for someone else in future